# lightbox plugin in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, lightbox

I am trying this thing for 2 days, but I can't understand what the bug here. I try to use lightbox plugin in my codeigniter project, but it does not show the expected result, rather it does not show any error too.

This is between  where I include my necessary file:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/core.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/manual_change.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/pre_change.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
```

I also include the function of lightbox:

```
$(function() {
$('a.lightbox').lightBox({
     'imageLoading': "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/lightbox-ico-loading.gif",
     'imageBtnClose': "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/lightbox-btn-close.gif",
     'imageBtnPrev': "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/lightbox-btn-prev.gif",
     'imageBtnNext': "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/lightbox-btn-next.gif",
     'imageBlank': "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/lightbox-blank.gif"
  }); // Select all links with lightbox class
});
```

I have used the image in html as like following:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/Acer_AX1400.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/Acer_AX1400.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

The .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|jquery\.js\robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My file location is correct:
All Images to show are in:
**assets/img/products/**
All Images additional for lightbox are in:
**assets/img/**
All Javascript are in:
**assets/js/**
All CSS are in:
**assets/css/**

The page link is at first is:
localhost/shop/
[image]

The page clicking after on the image is:
localhost/shop/assets/img/products/Acer_AX1400.jpg
[image]

Comment: Link to your page so we can `inspect` in Developer tools and find the problem.

Comment: I am really sorry, I can't do it now. But, I can ensure you, Firebug does not show any type of error here.

Comment: Can you see any images or JS?  Because your .htaccess doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: I have edited some more details on my problem specification now, may it will answer your question.

Comment: Still looks like the JS isn't loaded/triggered and you just follow the anchor link.

Comment: Each JS file is loaded, but may be not triggered. Can you help me to find out the reason.

Comment: It will be hard to debug without seeing the actual page.

Comment: This is the link of the page:http://shopcart.softtechbd.netai.net/

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function before any of the `lightbox` elements is loaded, so basically none of them get the event listener binded.

To overcome this, either use the [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function or just load your current function at the end of your file, after all the `lightbox` anchors are loaded in DOM.

Comment: I do whatever you say, but it does not still work. you can check the link.

Comment: It still looks the same to me... The function with this: `$('a.lightbox').lightBox({...` needs to be called after `lightbox` anchors are set.